# How To Send XMPP Chat Message notification to android as well as IOS

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, swift3, xmpp

i Have implemented XMPP chat in IOS Swift 3.0 Now My question is how to send notification to device While we kill the app.

When the Application is in background XMPP is connected so that i can call local notification.

But what to do when one lost XMPP connection how to send push Notification.

is there is any server where we can initiate to send notification to particular device.

Please help regarding that

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a `Service`. That `Service` will run forever and connection to `XMPP` server will not be lost unless network on device is lost or turned off.

Also manage your notification code inside your `Service` class.

Comment: But How to access application when One Kill that App. this  is not possible in IOS.

Comment: I don't know about iOS. I recently made a XMPP chat client on Android. I used `Singleton` pattern and Services to get messages in background.

Comment: Ok That's Work in Android but will not in IOS using That Logic